# Using C# to extract some content and its correponding Xpath from an HTML page

Tags: c#, html, regex, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML file , which has the following content:

```
</div><div class="\"more-detail-caption\"">More Numbers :</div><div id="\"moreHLNumbers\"" title="\"HSBC" bank="" helpline="" number\"="" class="\"more-detail-text\""><a href='tel:18605002277'>1860 500 2277 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( Credit Card - From India )</a><br><a href='tel:18602662667'>1860 266 2667 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( Personal Banking - From India )</a><br><a href='tel:18605002255'>1860 500 2255 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( Personal Banking - From India )</a><br><a href='tel:18004192266'>1800 419 2266 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( Corporate Cards - From India )</a><br><a href='tel:18001026922'>1800 102 6922 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( Corporate Cards - From India )</a><br><a href='tel:18002673456'>1800 267 3456 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( HSBC Advance - From India )</a><br><a href='tel:18001022208'>1800 102 2208 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( HSBC Advance - From India )</a><br><a href='tel:18002663456'>1800 266 3456 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( HSBC Premier - From India )</a><br><a href='tel:18001034722'>1800 103 4722 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( HSBC Premier - From India )</a><br><a href='tel:+912266800001'>022 66800001 </a><a class='cchlOtherNoDescription'>( Credit Card - From Overseas )
```

I want to extract these numbers using regex along with its description . For instance: 
"1860 266 2667 ( Personal Banking - From India )". Along with this its corresponding xpath, using c#.
 Till now I have figured out the following code, which only is removing the extra tags and has defined the regex for extracting numbers.

```
    using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public class Program
    {

        private static string phoneReg = @"[\+]{0,1}(\d{10,13}|[\(][\+]{0,1}\d{2,}[\13)]*\d{5,13}|\d{2,6}[\-]{1}\d{2,13}[\-]*\d{3,13})";
        private static Regex phoneRegex = new Regex(phoneReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        public static void Main()
        {

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"C:\htmldoc\htmlsample.html");
            doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                            .Where(n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "style" || n.Name == "svg" || n.Name == "button"
                                  || n.Name == "li" || n.Name == "link" || n.Name == "img" || n.Name == "head" || n.Name == "header" || n.Name == "input")
                            .ToList()
                            .ForEach(n => n.Remove());
            var phoneMatches = phoneRegex.Matches(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\htmldoc\new.html", doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.Replace(@"\t", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am facing some issues to extract the numbers as well. 
Can someone please help me with the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, why wouldn't you want to use an html parser to do the job like Html agility pack : https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex. It sounds to me a lot more easy?

Comment: I am lready done that, I need Description alongwith the phone number. I am using HTMLAgilitypack.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that my solution would fit your exact need but it should be close, I think...

Use can use "ForEach" defined in MoreLinq if you prefer (instead of my ApplyForEachItem).

Just as reference, I used https://regex101.com/ to make my reges tests which seems great.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace SoQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        // private static string phoneReg = @"[\+]{0,1}(\d{10,13}|[\(][\+]{0,1}\d{2,}[\13)]*\d{5,13}|\d{2,6}[\-]{1}\d{2,13}[\-]*\d{3,13})";

        private static string phoneReg = @"\s+\d[ \d]+\r\n.+\r\n";

        private static Regex phoneRegex = new Regex(phoneReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"C:\temp\HTMLPage1.html");
            doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                            .Where(n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "style" || n.Name == "svg" || n.Name == "button"
                                  || n.Name == "li" || n.Name == "link" || n.Name == "img" || n.Name == "head" || n.Name == "header" || n.Name == "input")
                            .ToList()
                            .ForEach(n => n.Remove());
            var phoneMatches = phoneRegex.Matches(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);

            List<Tuple<string, string>> data = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

            ApplyForEachItem(phoneMatches, match =>
            {
                int indexFirstDigit = match.Value.IndexOfAny(new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' });

                string[] phoneAndDesc = match.Value.Substring(indexFirstDigit).Split("\r\n");
                data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(phoneAndDesc[0].Trim(), phoneAndDesc[1].Trim()));
            });

            ApplyForEachItem(data, item => Debug.Print($"Phone: '{item.Item1}', Desc = '{item.Item2}' \r\n"));
        }

        public static void ApplyForEachItem<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
        {
            if (enumerable == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (T t in enumerable)
            {
                action(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Phone: '1860 500 2277', Desc = '( Credit Card - From India )' 
Phone: '1860 266 2667', Desc = '( Personal Banking - From India )' 
Phone: '1860 500 2255', Desc = '( Personal Banking - From India )' 
Phone: '1800 419 2266', Desc = '( Corporate Cards - From India )' 
Phone: '1800 102 6922', Desc = '( Corporate Cards - From India )' 
Phone: '1800 267 3456', Desc = '( HSBC Advance - From India )' 
Phone: '1800 102 2208', Desc = '( HSBC Advance - From India )' 
Phone: '1800 266 3456', Desc = '( HSBC Premier - From India )' 
Phone: '1800 103 4722', Desc = '( HSBC Premier - From India )' 
Phone: '022 66800001', Desc = '( Credit Card - From Overseas )'
```

Comment: Extract description along with the number. (Ex.1860 266 2667 :  - Personal Banking - From India )

Comment: also getting the error " can't be inferred from the usages, try specified the type argument explicitly

Comment: Should be a closer solution to your need. I wonder.. you seems to try to steal or hack... You don't do that?

Comment: About can't be inferred, what version of Visual Studio and Frameowrk .net are you using ?

Comment: I am not stealing or hacking .Don't worry about that. :)

Comment: - getting error 1>------ Build started: Project: ScrapingHTML, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\SatoriTask\KBDataCuration\ScrapingHTML\Program.cs(31,13,31,29): error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Program.ApplyForEachItem<T>(IEnumerable<T>, Action<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: version : Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
Version 15.9.4